# Unable to install lmtest and sandwich

Tags: r

Good morning, I am unable to install the lmtest and sandwich package, i get the error code below:

package ‘lmtest’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Error in install.packages : ERROR: failed to lock directory ‘C:\Users\Edidionn Ibokete\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3’ for modifying
Try removing ‘C:\Users\Edidionn Ibokete\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3/00LOCK’

please can i get any assistance?

i tried downloading Rtools and it has not resolved the issue.  I have also tried locating the directory based on consultation with ChatGPT but to no avail.

Comment: Hi there. In terms of locating the directory, have you tried deleting the `00LOCK` file by navigating to `C:\Users\Edidionn Ibokete\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3`? If you're having trouble doing so through file explorer, maybe try using the command line? Alternatively, have you tried to uninstall and reinstall?